# Setting ImageView after Crop not working

Tags: android, image, camera, imageview

I've created a basic activity with an imageView and two buttons. 1 Button opens the gallery, the other opens the camera. Both of which pass the result into a image cropping library. The cropped image is saved and shown in the imageView.

The first I do this with either button, everything works smoothly. However on the second attempt the imageView does not get replaced but the image that has been saved has changed.

So basically the imageView doesn't change to the new image if it already has the first result.

Here's Code:

```
public void takeDisplayPicture(View view) {

    final String TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE = "Take Display Picture";

    Log.d(TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE, "Clicked");

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File photoFile = null;

        try {

            photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.e(TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE, "Error Occurred");

        }

        if (photoFile != null) {

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            Log.d(TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE, photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }

    } else {

        Log.d(TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE, "No Camera");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Camera Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {

    final String ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT = "On Activity Result";

    Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT, "Triggered");

    Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT, "Request Code: "+Integer.toString(requestCode)+" Result Code: "+Integer.toString(resultCode));

    Uri img = Uri.parse("file:///"+Config.APP_PATH+Config.APP_USER_PATH+"/"+Config.DISPLAY_PICTURE_NAME+".png");

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT, "Beginning Crop");

        Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT,img.toString());

        beginCrop(img, img);

    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {

        Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT, "Handling Crop");

        handleCrop(resultCode, result);

    } else if (requestCode == 2){

        Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT, "Gallery Image Returned");

        File file = new File(img.getPath());
        file.delete();

        Uri src = result.getData();

        Log.d(ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT, src.toString());

        beginCrop(src, img);

    }

}

private void beginCrop(Uri source, Uri output){

    final String BEGIN_CROP = "Begin Crop";

    Log.d(BEGIN_CROP, "Beginning");

    new Crop(source).output(output).asSquare().start(this);

}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {

    final String HANDLE_CROP = "Handle Crop";

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.d(HANDLE_CROP, "Set ImageView");
        displayPicture.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));

        try {

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Crop.getOutput(result));

        } catch (Exception e ){

            Log.d(HANDLE_CROP, "Error Occurred");

        }

    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {

        Log.d(HANDLE_CROP, "Error Occurred");

    }
}

String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    final String CREATE_IMAGE_FILE = "Create Image File";

    String fileName = "display_picture";

    File dir = new File(Config.APP_PATH+Config.APP_USER_PATH);

    dir.mkdirs();

    File image = new File(dir,fileName+".png");

    return image;
}

public void chooseFromGallery(View view) {

    final String CHOOSE_FROM_GALLERY = "Choose From Gallery";

    Log.d(CHOOSE_FROM_GALLERY, "Clicked");

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read `setImageURI`:

```
  if (mResource != 0 ||
            (mUri != uri &&
             (uri == null || mUri == null || !uri.equals(mUri)))) {
                  //Set URI...
  }
```

Basically, setImageURI only works if the Uri of the image isn't equal to the Uri you want to currently set. Your button doesn't work second time because `Crop.getOutput(result)` returns the same Uri everytime you press the button, so `setImageURI` does nothing.

To solve this, you can add `displayPicture.setImageURI(null);` before `displayPicture.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));`.